# What's wrong with this code? (Towers of Hanoi in scala recursive)

Tags: function, scala

I need help again. I don't know what's wrong with this code, can anyone please help me?

```
def moveTower(n: Int, source: Stack[Int], sink: Stack[Int], workspace: Stack[Int]):     Stack[Int] = {
    if (n == 1) {
      sink.push(source.pop.##)
    } else {
      moveTower(n - 1, source, workspace, sink)
      sink.push(source.pop.##)
      moveTower(n - 1, workspace, sink, source)
    }
  }

  var source = Stack[Int](5, 4, 3, 2, 1)
  var sink = Stack[Int]()
  var workspace = Stack[Int]()
  moveTower(source.length.toInt, source, sink, workspace)
  println(source, sink, workspace)
```

Comment: I tried with "println(moveTower(n, source, sink, workspace))", but it says that "n" isn't found.

Comment: In the python version, you supply it with `len(source)` instead of `n`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in line:

```
  println(moveTower(n, source, sink, workspace))
```

notice that `moveTower()` type is Unit its print `Unit.toString`